tasks package: how to add a space after counter
I want some whitespace after the counter for aesthetic reasons - similar to the same syntax in enumerate, except using enumitem. I can't seem to find a way to do it in the label definition.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[label=(\alph*)](3)
\task meat \task potatoes \task brocolli
\end{tasks}
\end{document}


In fact you can find a solution from the terminal or log warning, that is setting a larger value for label-width.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[label=(\alph*),label-width=14pt](3)
\task meat \task potatoes \task brocolli
\end{tasks}
\end{document}



Interesting - I was wondering how to fix those errors. By the way, all of them gave different numbers between 12 and 14 as the recommended minimum size. Is there a generic one? Will the 14pt space be exactly the same as the spacing in the enumerate environment?

The recommended values are the lengths of the labels (a), (b) and (c), respectively. You can use \sbox0{(a)}\the\wd0 to get the width of the \hbox{(a)}.
